# Which implementation of Priority Queue will be effective if there are huge number of insert operation?

Tags: java

Suppose that your application will have a huge number of insert operations, but
only a few remove the maximum operations. Which priority-queue implementation do
you think would be most effective: heap, unordered array, or ordered array?

Can anyone explain with an example?

Comment: Does https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2824/most-efficient-known-priority-queue-for-inserts or https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/524/does-there-exist-a-priority-queue-with-o1-extracts answer your question?

Comment: @DylanVanderBerg From PQ implementation using Heap, Unordered array or Ordered array which is more effective when we have huge insert operation and few remove operation in our application.

Comment: Try read this [article(priority queue)](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/)

Comment: How can an unordered array implement a priority queue? And what is wrong with `java.util.PriorityQueue` instead of either kind of array?

Comment: @user7790438 Question is from that article only, once see Exercise problem no 11.

Comment: @EJP There is nothing wrong but that is inbuilt and am implementing my own PQ

Comment: `Binary Heap` is the answer to your question. Because insertion operation in a binary heap runs in `O(log N)` and deletion of max/min also runs in `O(log N)`

Answer (score 0):

Similar question Have you seen http://gateoverflow.in/65570/gatebook-exam.
There are four implementations for priority queue: For your case Un-ordered preferable.

```
|Structure          | Insertion | Extract-max|
|----------         |---------- |------------|
|Unordered list     |   O(1)    |   O(n)     |
|Ordered list       |   O(n)    |   O(1)     |
|Binary Search Tree |  O(logn)  |   O(logn)  |
|Heap               |  O(logn)  |   O(logn)  |
----------------------------------------------
```